# collectionView is different after Screen Rotation

Tags: ios, iphone

I am overriding the method

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
   {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size     withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
  [self.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
  [self.collectionView reloadData];

}
```

In Method **cellForItemAtIndexPath**
i m changing alpha of one cell to 0.5.

But after reloading all cell looks Same  But Before reloading i can see that difference.
i Don't know what's the Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing alpha of a cell I am changing its background color with the alpha Value.And Now its working.